# Executing a Power Automate flow from YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-logic-apps, power-automate, azure-pipelines-yaml

Is there a way to use YAML (in an Azure Pipeline) to trigger a Power Automate flow (or a logic app) with parameters?

I can see how to do it the other way around: from Power Automate to trigger a Pipeline but not the other way.

Comment: Sure, have it as HTTP triggered and call it via a PowerShell script.  There's also the Invoke REST API task that you can use.

Comment: Thought so ! So I may aswell just call SharePoint directly via graph and not get the logic or power app involved

Answer (score 0):

We trigger Power Automate Flows by using the Azure DevOps [Invoke REST API task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops).   This needs to have a Service Connection of Generic type which is only used to specify the Server URL.

To use this, your Pipeline needs to use an [Agentless Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops) which you choose by clicking the ellipsis in the Pipeline and adding an agentless job.